# How to enable translation of the content of just one field/div in php7?

Tags: php-7, mysql-8.0, language-translation

I am trying to figure out how to enable users to translate the returned content of one field, such as a textarea.
I do not propose to use api's that would translate the whole of the site on click, but just one field or division.
To do that, I have stumbled upon a free widget from gTranslate that could do the job nicely. However, I cannot get it to work for my intended 'just one field' purpose.
I have tried to wrap this widget in an iframe, but still no joy [with my limited php knowledge.]
For this scenario, you can assume that I have a simple crud application that has the usual view/edit/delete routines on the index page. The table has just a few columns in it such as first_name, last_name and so on and a column called comment, which is the text area that I wish to translate. For this, you may assume any text field such as a blog, description, etc.
When View pressed, I fire up 'detail_view.php' which just presents the first name and the comment fields of that record. It is on this page that I wish to have the comment field to get translated. So to this end I thought I would use an iframe. The source of the iframe is a secondary page called 'details_translate_include.php.' It is in this page that I have placed the widget so that the user could select the language by pressing the relevant icon given from that widget.
But It does not work. The data does not get populated and the widget is outside of the iframe.

So, can I ask for your help please?

NB.: This approach may not be the ideal solution to get this going. So, if you are aware of an alternative solution I would be more than happy to listen to.

A. In my 'detail_view.php' I have:

```
<!-- /.row -->
```

```
         <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
            <label>First name:</label>    
                          <input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $xx; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Comment:</label>
                          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  name="comment"><?php echo $yy; ?></textarea>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="">
            <label>Comment: [repeated here to get the translation working]</label>
            <iframe src="details_translate_include.php" width='790' height='250' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'class="bordered-box"></iframe>
                        </div>  
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Return to main menu</button>
        </form>
```

B. In my 'details_translate_include.php' I have:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
?>  

<?php
if( isset( $_GET['recID'] )){
$yy=$_GET['comment'];
echo $yy; 
}  
?>              

<div>
<textarea name="comment"><?php echo $yy; ?></textarea>
</div>
```

The output looks like this:
[output error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te5Gr.png)

However, I would like to get the data returned and the widget to be inside of that division.

C. the content of the translate widget [which is freeware] is given below:

```
<!-- GTranslate: https://gtranslate.io/ -->
<a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|en');return false;" title="English" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-0px -0px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="16" width="16" alt="English" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|fr');return false;" title="French" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-200px -100px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="16" width="16" alt="French" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|de');return false;" title="German" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-300px -100px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="16" width="16" alt="German" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|it');return false;" title="Italian" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-600px -100px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="16" width="16" alt="Italian" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|fa');return false;" title="Persian" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-200px -500px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="16" width="16" alt="Persian" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|pt');return false;" title="Portuguese" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-300px -200px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="16" width="16" alt="Portuguese" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|ru');return false;" title="Russian" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-500px -200px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="16" width="16" alt="Russian" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|es');return false;" title="Spanish" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-600px -200px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="16" width="16" alt="Spanish" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|cy');return false;" title="Welsh" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-700px -500px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="16" width="16" alt="Welsh" /></a>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
a.gflag {vertical-align:middle;font-size:16px;padding:1px 0;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url(//gtranslate.net/flags/16.png);}
a.gflag img {border:0;}
a.gflag:hover {background-image:url(//gtranslate.net/flags/16a.png);}
#goog-gt-tt {display:none !important;}
.goog-te-banner-frame {display:none !important;}
.goog-te-menu-value:hover {text-decoration:none !important;}
body {top:0 !important;}
#google_translate_element2 {display:none!important;}
-->
</style>

<br /><select onchange="doGTranslate(this);"><option value="">Select Language</option><option value="en|ar">Arabic</option><option value="en|eu">Basque</option><option value="en|ca">Catalan</option><option value="en|zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified)</option><option value="en|zh-TW">Chinese (Traditional)</option><option value="en|da">Danish</option><option value="en|nl">Dutch</option><option value="en|en">English</option><option value="en|fi">Finnish</option><option value="en|fr">French</option><option value="en|de">German</option><option value="en|el">Greek</option><option value="en|hi">Hindi</option><option value="en|it">Italian</option><option value="en|no">Norwegian</option><option value="en|fa">Persian</option><option value="en|pl">Polish</option><option value="en|pt">Portuguese</option><option value="en|ru">Russian</option><option value="en|es">Spanish</option><option value="en|sv">Swedish</option><option value="en|tr">Turkish</option><option value="en|cy">Welsh</option></select><div id="google_translate_element2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit2() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element2');}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('6 7(a,b){n{4(2.9){3 c=2.9("o");c.p(b,f,f);a.q(c)}g{3 c=2.r();a.s(\'t\'+b,c)}}u(e){}}6 h(a){4(a.8)a=a.8;4(a==\'\')v;3 b=a.w(\'|\')[1];3 c;3 d=2.x(\'y\');z(3 i=0;i<d.5;i++)4(d[i].A==\'B-C-D\')c=d[i];4(2.j(\'k\')==E||2.j(\'k\').l.5==0||c.5==0||c.l.5==0){F(6(){h(a)},G)}g{c.8=b;7(c,\'m\');7(c,\'m\')}}',43,43,'||document|var|if|length|function|GTranslateFireEvent|value|createEvent||||||true|else|doGTranslate||getElementById|google_translate_element2|innerHTML|change|try|HTMLEvents|initEvent|dispatchEvent|createEventObject|fireEvent|on|catch|return|split|getElementsByTagName|select|for|className|goog|te|combo|null|setTimeout|500'.split('|'),0,{}))
/* ]]> */
</script>
```